# How to fix full registry key batch remove

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

I tried to find registry keys using this line:

```
REG Query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData /F "Need removed manually Add-In" /S
```

But it contains these subkeys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\145BA990C18DA984499E1D1F9A1BD64D
BB02C99E89C99CD4A8CC6A7AA7576194    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\Need removed manually Add-In\SimonFell\PocketSoap\psDime.dll

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\37AC9AD16C5204A4D9D92967A6699DEE
    BB02C99E89C99CD4A8CC6A7AA7576194    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\Need removed manually Add-In\SimonFell\PocketSoap\pSOAP32.dll

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\DFD1C740E6047204C8387A02138B234A
    BB02C99E89C99CD4A8CC6A7AA7576194    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\Need removed manually Add-In\SimonFell\PocketSoap\pocketHTTP.dll

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\F3A3DDBA307ACB945868E32C44414A5E
    BB02C99E89C99CD4A8CC6A7AA7576194    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\Need removed manually Add-In\SimonFell\PocketSoap\psProxy.dll

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\BB02C99E89C99CD4A8CC6A7AA7576194\InstallProperties
    DisplayName    REG_SZ    Need removed manually Add-In

End of search: 5 match(es) found.
```

When I tried to delete using with a script:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('REG Query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData /F "Need removed manually Add-In" /S') DO REG delete "%%a" /f
```

I delete first full key successful but after I that, I get an error because the script is trying to delete the second line with string detail:

```
REG delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\145BA990C18DA984499E1D1F9A1BD64D" /f
```

The operation completed successfully.

```
REG delete "    BB02C99E89C99CD4A8CC6A7AA7576194    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\Need removed manually Add-In\SimonFell\PocketSoap\psDime.dll" /f
```

> ERROR: Invalid key name.
>   Type "REG DELETE /?" for usage.

How can I delete only the actual keys and avoid this error?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Batch remove full registry key using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52055013/batch-remove-full-registry-key-using-for-loop), asked earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my response as provided belatedly in the duplicate question.

Use the `Reg Query` search option, **`/F`**, and search in data values only, **`/D`**, Then to remove the value lines and the search count you can use `Find` to output only those lines containing the string `HKEY_`.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData"
Set "Str=Need removed manually Add-In"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('REG Query "%Key%" /S /F "%Str%" /D^|Find "HKEY_"'
) Do Echo=Reg Delete "%%A" /F
Pause
```

Change the values in lines `2` and `3` to suit your specific requirements.

*If you're happy with the output, simply remove `Echo=` from the penultimate line and optionally remove the last line. (Please note that I don't recommend deleting registry keys in this manner so the decision is yours as to whether you should have a registry backup prior to deleting these keys)*

---

Note that you may need to Run as Administrator to delete keys under `HKLM`.